# How to queue google analytics gtag events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, turbolinks

I'm working on a Rails app, which has [turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) enabled. Because of turbolinks, I have to defer the loading of the `gtag('config')` call, which would track the pageview, and set-up GA with the tracking ID:

```
<head>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(event) {
      if(typeof(gtag) == 'function'){
        gtag('config', '<%= Rails.application.config.ga_tracking_id %>', {
          'page_title' : event.target.title,
          'page_path': event.data.url.replace(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname, "")
        });
      }
    })
  </script>
</head>
```

This appears to be [the recommended practice for using `gtag()` with turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/73#issuecomment-460028854). If I don't do this, the GA `pageview` event won't get logged after the first page, because of the way turbolinks hacks the page refresh behavior.

In order to log specific Google Analytics events from my Rails controllers, I put some content into the Rails flash object, which a JavaScript function then picks-up:

My controller:

```
flash[:log_event] = {
  'event_category' => 'general',
  'event_name' => 'login',
  'method' => 'facebook'
}
```

My layout has a simple Rails->JavaScript bridge:

```
<script>
  handleLogEvent(<%= flash[:log_event].to_json.html_safe %>)
</script>
```

The handleLogEvent method simply calls `gtag('event')`:

```
  function handleLogEvent(fromRails) {
    if (fromRails) {                                          
      const eventData = fromRails;
      const eventName = fromRails.event_name;
      delete eventData.event_name;
      gtag('event', eventName, eventData);
    }
  }
```

**THE PROBLEM**

The `gtag('event')` fires **before** `gtag('config')` does. As a result, it doesn't work at all. If I add a timeout of a couple of seconds, it works just fine. (e.g. `setTimeout(function () { gtag('event', eventName, eventData) }, 2000);`).

Since the `gtag` function exists, I'm wondering if there's a correct way for me to queue events that happen before the `gtag('config')` function has been called? For now it's just going to be this one event.

**STUFF I'VE TRIED**

I've had success with adding a second listener for `turbolinks:load`:

```
  document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(event) {
    if(typeof(gtag) == 'function'){
      gtag('event', eventName, eventData);
    }
  });
```

It seems a big kludgey though. I imagine the first listener (that calls `gtag('config')` could fail, leading to unpredictable results.

Comment: Any luck on this one @antun? I'm hitting the same problem. Trying to setup a separate global event queue that gets data added to it until gtag has loaded.

Comment: @dtbaker I stuck with the second listener workaround. I didn't find any cleaner approach.